# Pricing table query In MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I've 3 tables in MYSQL one is pricing, transactions and billing. I've 100 Customers, 10 out of them having special rates. Remaining 90 customers having same pricing structure. While billing i want to get the prices accordingly.

Ex

**Pricing Table**

```
Cust   prod   price   fromdate    todate
001    apple   5.25   01-09-2015  31-12-9999
002    apple   4.25   01-09-2015  31-12-9999
999    apple   6.00   01-09-2015  31-12-9999 default value
001    Orange  8.25   01-09-2015  31-12-9999
999    Orange  9.00   01-09-2015  31-12-9999 default value
```

**Trans Table**

```
Date        cust   prod      qty 
10-09-2015  001    apple     2.0 
10-09-2015  002    apple     3.0 
10-09-2015  002    Orange    3.0 
10-09-2015  050    apple     3.0 
10-09-2015  050    Orange    2.0 
10-09-2015  001    Orange    2.0
```

Third result table.
**Bill table **

```
Date        cust   prod    price   qty  amount

10-09-2015  002    apple    4.25   3.0   12.75 Which is present in PriceTbl

10-09-2015  002    Orange   9.00   3.0   27.00 Default Price Orange

10-09-2015  050    apple    6.00   3.0   18.00 Default Price Apple

10-09-2015  050    Orange   9.00   2.0   18.00 Default Price Orange
```

How to get the default values for customer number `050` for all products and 
for customer number `002` for Oranges.

Comment: do a `join` between the tables.

Comment: your question is not clear, so show what output you required...

Comment: I want to update / set the price column based on cust column from Pricing table.

Comment: Join is successful only when cust code is present in Pricing table.

Comment: How are you identifying Default value? with cust code `999`??

Comment: That is what my problem, I want to try  if (pricingTbl.cust<>transTbl.cust,999,cust)

Comment: Please add expected result and if possible table creation scripts.

Comment: REATE TABLE `PriceTbl` (
 `Cust` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `prod` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `price` FLOAT(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `fromdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `todate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `transtbl` (
 `trdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `cust` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `prod` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `qty` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `BillTbl` (
 `trdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `cust` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `prod` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `price` FLOAT(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `qty` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `amount` FLOAT(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  `Trans`.`Date`,
  `Trans`.`cust`,
  `Trans`.`prod`,
  IF(ISNULL(`Pricing`.`price`, `DefPrices`.`price`, `Pricing`.`price`)) AS `price`,
  `Trans`.`qty`,
  IF(ISNULL(`Pricing`.`price`, `DefPrices`.`price`, `Pricing`.`price`)) * `Trans`.`qty` AS `amount`
FROM `Trans`
LEFT JOIN `Pricing` ON `Pricing`.`Cust` = `Trans`.`cust` AND `Trans`.`prod` = `Pricing`.`prod`
LEFT JOIN `Pricing` AS `DefPrices` ON `DefPrices`.`prod` = `Trans`.`prod` AND `DefPrices`.`Cust` = '999'
WHERE `Trans`.`cust` IN ('002','050')
```